# Matching char based on lookup table using base R -- e.g., plyr::revalue

Tags: r

I'm looking to reproduce the behavior of `plyr::revalue` using base R. I want replaces the values of `foo` below based on a lookup table. The `plyr::revalue` does what I want. Tips for how to accomplish this in base R? Happy to use a data.frame or a named vector for the lookup.

```
lookupDF <- data.frame(shortName=c("app","or","ba","ma","unk"),
                       longName=c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango", "Something Else"))

lookupVec <- lookupDF$longName
names(lookupVec) <- lookupDF$shortName

foo <- c("or","app","def","app","abc","ban")
plyr::revalue(foo,lookupVec)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `lookupVec[foo]`?

Comment: Yeah. I guess I can do something like this ``` bar <- lookupVec[foo]
bar[is.na(bar)] <- foo[is.na(bar)]
names(bar) <- NULL
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment, this should work I think.

```
bar <- lookupVec[foo]
bar[is.na(bar)] <- foo[is.na(bar)]
names(bar) <- NULL
bar
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You could use `ifelse(is.na(lookupVec[foo]), foo, lookupVec[foo])` combining the first two lines into one.